# Sheduled event disappearing after another has finished

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anybody know how WordPress stores it's CronJob events? I'm developing a plugin with multiple concurrent CronJobs, which behaves really strange. When configuring the plugin the first Event will generate some page data over a period of roughly 10-15 mins and is split into multiple packages. These packages will reschedule themselves to get the maximum running time, without hitting the script execution limit. However when the first CronJob is executed, the user can start a second one (not the same one, it's from another section), which will always result in the second one being scheduled, staying in standby and getting removed after the first one has finished an execution.

We had problems with long running CronJobs and the database cache before: Some of our data is bundled into an option and inserting data into this package will overwrite changes made outside of the CronJob. Maybe something similar is happening here. For reference: The reshedule of the first CronJob happens inside said CronJob. Could that be a problem too?

This is how the error is behaving:

1. Init
2. Cron 1 is sheduled to a past timestamp.
3. Cron 1 is starting.
4. Cron 2 is sheduled to a past timestamp.
5. Cron 1 is working.
6. Cron 1 is finished.
7. Cron 1 is resheduled to a new timestamp.
8. Cron 2 gets removed from the event queue.
9. Cron 1 is starting...

I have checked everything that correlates to the scripts themselves: The events are properly registered, have a unique argument (just in case) and even pull a new version of the database options they change, before doing so. Limits are set beforehand and every related function is wrapped in a try-catch-block.

My questions so far: Does anybody know what can cause a CronJob do get deleted (besides "wp_clear_sheduled_hook")? Does WordPress store the events as an option? Can a CronJob overwrite these settings, when it is running for a long time?

Thanks for your help and greetings

SOLUTION: Thanks @kyon147 for pointing out that WordPress is using the wp-options table to store information about the sheduled events. In case anyone has similar problems: Wordpress will load ALL options into it's cache, when it is called. Meaning when starting Cron1 the "cron"-array with your events might look like this:

```
array('cron1' => 'time')
```

When something is changing this option while the script is still runing, this  change will not be reflected to the script. Meaning the array will still be as above, even when an event is added from another script/session. So when resheduling the event INSIDE Cron1 WordPress took the array above, not the new one. This resulted in the changes being reset to the state, when Cron1 was started and thus the event appearing missing.

Comment: Wordpress stores the schedules in a row option called cron in wp_options in the database.

Can you please share your code as without it we can't see the logic of it.

Comment: Hey there, I have added some snippets. I hope they are of help (sorry for the missing format in snippet 1). EDIT: Regarding snippet 2: The conditional for the second time calculation is a leftover workaround. I tried to shedule it to a later timestamp than the first CronJob would usually take.

Comment: So you want to only run cron2 if cron1 has ran? It is still a little unclear what you are trying to do. You also have to remember WPCron only runs when a user visits the website, so for proper cron you have to create a cronjob within the server using crontab -e.

Comment: Running them concurrently seems to be impossible, as WordPress should prevent a CronJob from running again withing 10 minutes. At least that's what I read. Our goal is to let Cron1 finish and shedule Cron2 while it is running. I think the problem is the "cron"-option you mentioned earlier. When Cron1 is starting WordPress is loading the whole option table and caches their values. So a newly sheduled event, would not be in the array "cron". Resheduling the event inside it'sown function overwrites the old array to aversion where cron1 is resheduled, but cron2 is missing.

Comment: Do you know any way to advise WordPress to update it's database cache before saving?

Comment: Without knowing why you need to run one after the other and what the cron jobs are doing it is hard to advise on a solution. Rather than cron1 and cron2 you need to explain what they actually do. There could be a better way of running the whole thing.

Comment: Actually my problem was solved by your first answer, but for completeness: Cron1 is a script to fetch a few thousand rows from an API. Usually this takes 6 minutes and has been split into 9 packages to reduce the runtime of each call. So Cron1 is a segmented fetching process, that will reshedule itself to get the data as fast as possible. Cron2 is a analysis process that will run anywhere from 1 second to 5 minutes. It takes every post and generates data based on their settings. I will update the question with a more detailed explanation. PS: Thank you :)

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)